# How can I pick Bookings from given period in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This is my table.

```
post_id     meta_key        meta_value
--------    --------        ----------
10          booking_from    2017-01-20
10          booking_to      2017-01-25
11          booking_from    2017-02-20
11          booking_to      2017-02-25
```

How can I pick post_id of if 2017-01-22 to 2017-01-26 has booking. Currently I have booking on this date.

I want to pick if the given date period has a booking using SQL query

Comment: Can you share what expected result you are looking?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to aggregate over your table by the `post_id` and check to make sure that `booking_from` date be on or before `'2017-01-22'` and the `booking_to` date be on or after `'2017-01-26'`.  A trick here is to use `MIN()` and `MAX()` to identify the booking from and to dates.

```
SELECT post_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING MIN(meta_value) <= '2017-01-22' AND
       MAX(meta_value) >= '2017-01-26'
```

This would check that the entire range is completely covered by a booking.  If instead you want to check whether any existing booking overlaps at all with this range, we can slightly change the query to the following:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING MIN(meta_value) BETWEEN '2017-01-22' AND '2017-01-26' OR
       MAX(meta_value) BETWEEN '2017-01-22' AND '2017-01-26'
```

Here is a **demo** for the second query:

## Rextester